# Selenium Index out of range

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


elemental_list = []

chrome_driver = Service(executable_path="Users\David\Desktop\Python\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_driver)

for page in range(21):

    page_url = "https://www.fastexpert.com/top-real-estate-agents/florida/?page=" + str(page)
    driver.get(page_url)
    title = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//h3/a")
    location = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'RTLOCATION')]/p/a")

    for i in range(len(title)):
        elemental_list.append([title[i].text, location[i].text])

for element in elemental_list:
    print(element)

driver.close()
```

This is my code to scrape data from that specific website. If I run the loop two times, it gives me the output I want. If I run the code for the whole 20 pages, I run into an index Error, and I can't figure out why that is.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\David\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 19, in <module>
    elemental_list.append([title[i].text, location[i].text])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

What do I miss or oversee because the loop should fill an empty list, and there should be no index error as the list is as big as the data I put into it, or what did I miss?

Comment: You don't have as many locations as titles, which is causing the issue.

Comment: How can I include the once without a location so that it only gives me the name and loops through the rest?

Comment: print len(title) and len(location)

Comment: Use a parser like BeautifulSoup to parse the HTML, get details element-wise, and keep the location blank when not present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an HTML parser to effectively find and use blank values for broken elements, i.e. which don't have a location.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

elemental_list = []

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

for page in range(1, 21):
    page_url = "https://www.fastexpert.com/top-real-estate-agents/florida/?page=" + str(page)
    print(page_url)
    driver.get(page_url)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "section.TOP25AGENTSE10.RTAGENTCOLUMN div.TOPREPT_RRT")))

    agents = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml').find('section', {'class': 'TOP25AGENTSE10 RTAGENTCOLUMN'}).find_all('div', {'class': 'TOPREPT_RRT'})

    for agent in agents:
        elemental_list.append((agent.find('h3').find('a').text.strip(), agent.find('div', {'class': 'RTLOCATION'}).find('p').text.strip())) if agent.find('div', {'class': 'RTLOCATION'}) else elemental_list.append((agent.find('h3').text, ''))

for element in elemental_list:
    print(element)

driver.quit()
```

In this code, I used BeautifulSoup as a parser to parse the HTML. And I am taking the entire element, so that title and location can be effectively matched and replaced with a blank value, if not present.

Output:

```
('DeWayne Carpenter', 'Miami, FL')
('Kirk Kessel', 'Satellite Beach, FL')
('Chris Creegan', 'Maitland, FL')
('Jeff Tricoli Team', 'Lake Worth, FL')
('Jeffrey Borham', 'Palm Harbor, FL')
('Brenda Wade', 'Valrico, FL')
('Sandy Blanton', 'Pensacola, FL')
('Welch Team', 'St Augustine, FL')
('Liz Piedra', 'Spring Hill, FL')
('Mike Gagliardi', 'Port Orange, FL')
('David & Toni Zarghami', 'Sarasota, FL')
('Jeffrey G. Funk', 'Windermere, FL')
('Sarah and Tim Caudill', 'New Smyrna Beach, FL')
('Kevin Bartlett', 'Estero, FL')
('Christian Bennett', 'Trinity, FL')
('Ben Laube', 'Windermere, FL')
('Nichole Roberts', 'Ocala, FL')
('Sandra Rathe', 'Davie, FL')
('Cynthia Fazzini', 'Palm Harbor, FL')
('Jayson Burtch', 'Port Charlotte, FL')
('Lisa Carroll', "Land O' Lakes, FL")
('Jennifer Fieo', 'Brandon, FL')
('Barrett Spray', 'Oviedo, FL')
('JoAnn and Tom Jacobs', 'Tallahassee, FL')
('Jennifer Wemert', 'Orlando, FL')
('Chris Grant', 'Punta Gorda, FL')
('Christina Griffin', 'Lutz, FL')
('Chris Heine Jr.', 'Palm Beach Gardens, FL')
('Michelle Thomas', 'Naples, FL')
('Kendall Caputo', 'Flagler Beach, FL')
('Mark Hiller', 'Niceville, FL')
("Sellin' With CC Team", 'Atlantic Beach, FL')
('Crystal McCall', 'Ocala, FL')
('Stacie Brown Kelly', 'Oviedo, FL')
('Robert Todd Schroth', 'Altamonte Springs, FL')
('Eddie Blanco', 'Hialeah, FL')
('Michelle Martin', 'Destin, FL')
('James Clark', 'Altamonte Springs, FL')
('Belinda Ravan', 'St Augustine, FL')
('David Lovitch', 'Apollo Beach, FL')
('Damian Costantino', 'Tallahassee, FL')
('Carrie Courtney & Company', 'Orlando, FL')
('Tracy Jones', 'Venice, FL')
('Erica Jolles', 'Saint Johns, FL')
('Phil Aitken', 'Jacksonville, FL')
('Brenda Bianchi', 'Seminole, FL')
('Vanessa Leonard', 'Palm Harbor, FL')
('Simon Simaan', 'Windermere, FL')
('Heather Edwards', 'Fort Lauderdale, FL')
('Nick Demers', 'Port Charlotte, FL')
('Jennifer Wemert', 'Orlando, FL')
("Annie O'Sullivan", 'Land O Lakes, FL')
('Mike Darda', 'Cape Coral, FL')
('The Barb Brooks Team', 'Port Charlotte , FL')
('Scott Garrison', 'Winter Springs, FL')
('Kathleen Batterton', 'Pace, FL')
('Mark Rucco', 'Delray Beach, FL')
('William Eggeling', 'Port St Lucie, FL')
('Larry & Joy Mastropieri', 'Boca Raton, FL')
('Brandie Mathison-Klein', 'Clermont, FL')
('Tony Baroni Team', 'Valrico, FL')
('Greg Lynn', 'Boca Raton, FL')
('Barbara Schluraff', 'Cocoa Beach, FL')
('Eden Jordan', 'Fleming Island, FL')
('Jason Pithers', 'Tampa, FL')
('Frank N Falbo', 'Ocala, FL')
('Michael Simpkins', 'Wimauma, FL')
('Eric Jenkins, P.A.', 'Palm Harbor, FL')
('Kathy Damewood', 'Englewood, FL')
('Casandra Vann', 'Lakeland, FL')
('Saud Rai (CRS)', 'Homestead, FL')
('Lisa Jackson', 'Cape Coral, FL')
('Kelly Fischer', 'Vero Beach, FL')
('Cindy Gavin', 'Jacksonville, FL')
('Ashley Yates', 'Ocala, FL')
('Belinda Ravan', 'St Augustine, FL')
('David Lovitch', 'Apollo Beach, FL')
('Damian Costantino', 'Tallahassee, FL')
('Carrie Courtney & Company', 'Orlando, FL')
('Tracy Jones', 'Venice, FL')
('Erica Jolles', 'Saint Johns, FL')
('Phil Aitken', 'Jacksonville, FL')
('Brenda Bianchi', 'Seminole, FL')
('Vanessa Leonard', 'Palm Harbor, FL')
('Simon Simaan', 'Windermere, FL')
('Heather Edwards', 'Fort Lauderdale, FL')
('Nick Demers', 'Port Charlotte, FL')
('John Muccigrosso', 'Winter Park, FL')
('Alexander Haigh', 'Stuart, FL')
('Scott Reynolds', 'Vero Beach, FL')
('Jon Carroll', 'Jacksonville, FL')
('Chris Winn', 'Orlando, FL')
('Chrissi Jasso', 'Winter Haven, FL')
('Bryan W. Nelson', 'Mt Dora, FL')
('Phillip Parisi', 'Palm City, FL')
('Jose Calvo', 'Royal Palm Beach, FL')
('Dominick Florio', 'Winter, FL')
('Misty Morrison', 'Melbourne, FL')
('John Mamo', 'Spring Hill, FL')
('Christina Rampersad', 'Orlando, FL')
('Aaron Novello', 'Plantation, FL')
('The Homan Group', 'Spring Hill, FL')
('Brian Madsen', 'South Daytona, FL')
('Casey Tray', 'Lakeland, FL')
('Bruce and Michelle Brunk', 'Lecanto, FL')
('Lockhart Walseth Team', 'Treasure Island, FL')
('The Rocco Group', 'Jacksonville, FL')
('Zachary Coletti', 'Sebastian, FL')
('Joseph Doher', 'Orlando, FL')
('Nicole Miller', 'Coral Springs, FL')
('Rob Hastings', 'Atlantic Beach, FL')
('Donna Concannon', 'New Smyrna Beach, FL')
('Adam Fernandez', 'Tampa, FL')
('Chase Walseth', 'St. Petersburg, FL')
('Jonathan Mills', 'Gainesville, FL')
('Alex Vastardis', 'Orlando, FL')
('Jennifer Hendry', 'Jacksonville, FL')
('James Sommers', 'Cape Coral, FL')
('Brian Boles', 'Boca, FL')
('Ryan Chiodo', 'Naples, FL')
('Christina Barone', 'Tampa, FL')
('122. Angela Lutzi Dellatore ', '')
('Rebecca Parker', 'Jacksonville, FL')
('Rachael Barach', 'Fort Lauderdale, FL')
('Michael Rolewicz', 'Jacksonville Beach, FL')
('Andy Waterman', 'Melbourne, FL')
('Philippa Main', 'Tampa, FL')
('Mark Ramey', 'Jacksonville, FL')
('Brian Hyser', 'Winter Park, FL')
('Barbara Zorn', 'Cocoa Beach, FL')
('Denise Madan', 'Miami Lakes, FL')
('Cindi Infiesto', 'Alva, FL')
('Melissa Ricks', 'Jacksonville Beach, FL')
('Kathleen Carlson', 'Celebration, FL')
('Autumn Makin', 'Winter Garden, FL')
('Brian Helgemo', 'Punta Gorda, FL')
('Erik Hansen', 'Pensacola, FL')
('David Dorman', 'Ocoee, FL')
('Deena Carvajal', 'Orlando, FL')
('Dada McGlynn', 'Gainesville, FL')
('Anthony Askowitz', 'Miami, FL')
('Nancy/Andre Tamburello', 'Apollo Beach, FL')
('Dane Aho', 'Fort Walton Beach, FL')
('Chuck Shaver', 'Deland, FL')
('LISSETTE SANCHEZ', 'Orlando, FL')
('Stacey Glenn', 'Ft Myers, FL')
('Kyle Kleinman', 'Miami, FL')
('Trish Waller', 'Valrico, FL')
('Billee Silva', 'Fort Myers, FL')
('Robert Christiano', 'Winter Park, FL')
('Albert Pavon', 'West Palm Beach, FL')
('Raymond Mihara', 'Tampa, FL')
('Mario Avalos', 'Miami, FL')
('Sean Bates', 'Siesta Key, FL')
('Mario Zendeli', 'Winter Park, FL')
('Shane Reynolds', 'Vero Beach, FL')
('Kevin Yankow', 'Fort Myers, FL')
('Marc George', 'Orlando, FL')
('Joel Freis', 'Miami Lakes, FL')
('Lisa Treu', 'Delray Beach, FL')
('Suzie Connolly', 'Ponte Vedra Beach, FL')
('Lisa Frins', 'Islamorada, FL')
('McKinley Navaroli', 'Palm Beach Gardens, FL')
('David Weinstein', 'Boca Raton, FL')
('Eve Metlis', 'Orlando, FL')
('Jennifer Calenda', 'Punta Gorda, FL')
('Lindsay Voss', 'Orlando, FL')
('Hettie Spooner', 'Tallahassee, FL')
('Matt Davies', 'Orlando, FL')
('Dawn Johnson', 'Newberry, FL')
('Jonathan Alexander', 'Boca Raton, FL')
('Jennifer Lee', 'Gainesville, FL')
('Karen Arbutine', 'Lake Maey , FL')
('TERESA SANTANA', 'Weston, FL')
('Kristen Comstock', 'Apollo Beach, FL')
('Gia Freer', 'Boca Raton, FL')
('Joey Lamielle', 'Sarasota, FL')
('Janina Wozniak', 'Tampa, FL')
('Carole Smith', 'Miami, FL')
('Kelly Parks', 'Clearwater Beach, FL')
('Kelley Blackburn', 'Plant City, FL')
('182. Amanda Eckart ', '')
('Lee Goldberg', 'Winter Park, FL')
('David Price', 'St. Petersburg, FL')
('Lindsey Whitney', 'Satellite Beach, FL')
('Tonya Zimmern', 'Gulf Breeze, FL')
('187. Marcus Larrea ', '')
('Christopher Moore', 'Orange Park, FL')
('Jane McCroary', 'Treasure Island, FL')
('Diane Keane', 'Delray Beach, FL')
('191. Kevin Hanley ', '')
('Gitta Urbainczyk PA', 'Lake Mary, FL')
('Lisa Gottesman', 'Fort Myers, FL')
('Victor Cruz', 'Miami Lakes, FL')
('The Cotton Team 904 at Round Table Realty', 'Saint Johns, FL')
('Kris White', 'Port Charlotte, FL')
('Jessica Ross', 'Lakewood Ranch, FL')
('Chris Loschiavo', 'Winter Haven, FL')
('Daniel DeRogatis', 'Delray Beach, FL')
('200. Chip Hartung ', '')
('201. Kyle Thompson ', '')
('202. Amy Miller ', '')
('203. Theo Fulger ', '')
('204. Jimmy Cunningham ', '')
('Tyler Fitz', 'St. Augustine, FL')
('Darrell & Angela Turner', 'Santa Rosa Beach, FL')
('Christie Frankenstein', 'Apollo Beach, FL')
('Samantha Marker', 'Cape Coral, FL')
('Alex Fink', 'Palm Beach Gardens,, FL')
('Luana Leventhal', 'Davenport, FL')
('Ken Jones', 'Tampa, FL')
('Jeff Riber', 'Jacksonville, FL')
('Debra Valdes', 'Tampa, FL')
('Todd Ostrander', 'Melbourne, FL')
('215. Rick A Brown ', '')
('Jeff Grant', 'Palm Beach Gardens, FL')
('VANYA and DIMO DEMIREV', 'Bonita Springs, FL')
('Jesse Warmka', 'Palm Coast, FL')
('Zachary Mazur', 'Delray Beach, FL')
('220. Kevin McPherson ', '')
('221. Holly Dandridge Madden ', '')
('Maria & John Hoffman', 'Tampa, FL')
('Dexter Brandao', 'Miami, FL')
('Chris Holko', 'Apollo Beach, FL')
('Marcia Kasper', 'Ocala, FL')
('Jennifer Thompson', 'Sarasota, FL')
('Jennifer Martin', 'Indialantic, FL')
('Lesli Burkhead', 'Homestead, FL')
('Yochi Melnick', 'Naples, FL')
('Bobby & Lindsey Mims', 'Lake Mary, FL')
('Nicole Cossette', 'Brandon, FL')
('Tammy Freilich', 'The Villages, FL')
('Rachel Queen', 'Clearwater, FL')
('Margaret Pittas', 'Ocala, FL')
('Gustavo Moreiara', 'Miami, FL')
('Lindsey Mims', 'Lake Mary, FL')
('Gabe Stephani', 'Niceville, FL')
('Tristina Hill', 'Deland, FL')
('Jeff, Tami & Karson Jones', 'Palm Harbor, FL')
('Nathan Mathers', 'Bradenton, FL')
('Jeremy Dysch & Josie Mittleman', 'Boca Raton, FL')
('Adam Silk', 'Jacksonville, FL')
('Tiffany Packard', 'Cape Coral, FL')
('Sascha Davis', 'Altamonte Springs, FL')
('245. Jason Young ', '')
('Vernon Ubico', 'Miami, FL')
('247. Jenny Schaffer ', '')
('Nicola Hughes', 'Deltona, FL')
('249. Steve Thomas ', '')
('Garrett Bell', 'Melbourne, FL')
('Garrett Bell', 'Melbourne, FL')
('Shelley Duke', 'Tallahassee, FL')
('Chris Snow', 'St Augustine, FL')
('Tiffany Licata', 'Kissimmee, FL')
('255. Jackie Griffin ', '')
('Matt Roberts', 'Oxford, FL')
('AJ & Courtney Ackerman', 'Cape Coral, FL')
('Kevin Jacobs', 'Apollo Beach, FL')
('259. Wael Georgey ', '')
('Kathy Weithman', 'Port Charlotte, FL')
('Ginger Bennett', 'Odessa, FL')
('Bret Crino', 'Tampa, FL')
('Brian Pearl', 'Boca Raton, FL')
('264. Laura Christiano ', '')
('Debbie Schoonover', 'The Villages, FL')
("Jacob O\\'Donnell", 'Tallahassee, FL')
('Stacy Koury', 'Boca Raton, FL')
('Sherry Flathman', 'Bradenton, FL')
('Kathleen Comerford', 'Sarasota, FL')
('David Tran', 'Bonita Springs, FL')
('Bradley Fairman', 'Melbourne, FL')
('Ross Hardy', 'Spring Hill, FL')
('Shellie Raymond', 'Melbourne, FL')
('Quan Diep, PA', 'Palm Beach Gardens, FL')
('Kevin Shelly', 'Bonita Springs, FL')
('Jason Prieto', 'Winter Haven, FL')
('Michael Constantine', 'Trinity, FL')
('Marie Evans', 'Ocala, FL')
('279. Andy Mandel ', '')
('280. Kristi Stewart ', '')
('Terry and Laurie Carlson', 'Cape Coral, FL')
('Christopher Spina', 'Bonita Springs, FL')
('Tobin Bossola', 'Jacksonville, FL')
('Karlene Grimes', 'Saint Cloud, FL')
('285. Chris Feamster ', '')
('Megan Ross', 'Melbourne, FL')
('Dave Magua', 'Boca Raton, FL')
('Marie Orlando', 'Naples, FL')
('Susan Carleton', 'Perdido Key, FL')
('290. Tenisha Williams ', '')
('Jose Medina', 'Miami, FL')
('Jean Scott', 'Oviedo, FL')
('293. Silvia Mozer ', '')
('RONI STERIN', 'Weston, FL')
('295. Joy Pratt ', '')
('Katie Rawnsley', 'Palm Beach Gardens, FL')
('Samuel Fugina', 'Miramar, FL')
('Yasha Wells', ', Championsgate, FL')
('Michael Dylan Smith', 'Pace, FL')
('300. Daniel Araque ', '')
('Marie A. Collins, P.A.', 'Saint Cloud, FL')
('Matt Gelling', 'Boca Raton, FL')
('George Crawford', 'Apopka, FL')
('304. Heather Strazinsky ', '')
('Ileana Rodriguez', 'South Miami, FL')
('Danny Pena', 'Orlando, FL')
('Ernest Van Glahn', "Land O' Lakes, FL")
('Helen Y. Carlsen', 'Sarasota, FL')
('Kellie Jankowski', 'Ponte Vedra, FL')
('Chris Bessette', 'Orlando, FL')
('Jill Helgren', 'Treasure Island, FL')
('Cash Ealey', 'Tampa, FL')
('Kendall Kruszynski', 'Jupiter, FL')
('Edgar Rhenals', 'Davie, FL')
('Nicole Parker', 'Hernando Beach, FL')
('Nicholas Vavoulis', 'Trinity, FL')
('Cynthia Abbey', 'Rockledge, FL')
('Tommy Mack', 'Key West, FL')
('Levi Stubbs', 'Valrico, FL')
('320. Anthony Alfarone ', '')
('321. Lance Willard ', '')
('Liliana Whittington', 'The Villages, FL')
('Martha Loss', 'Tampa, FL')
('Beth McCain', 'Palm Coast, FL')
('Jeff Naylor', 'Tallahassee, FL')
('Chad Bishop', 'Fort Lauderdale, FL')
('SAL GIULIANO', 'North Port, FL')
('Lourdes Sliwa', 'Satellite Beach, FL')
('329. Alex Greenwood ', '')
('Elaine Samaan', 'Jacksonville, FL')
('ALICIA LEVITAN', 'Fort Lauderdale, FL')
('Kyle Gruber', 'Palm Harbor, FL')
('James Saffell', 'Spring Hill, FL')
('334. Larry Fischer ', '')
('335. Monika Phillips ', '')
('336. Bob Barwald ', '')
('337. Justin Core ', '')
('Eric Krall', 'Merritt Island, FL')
('Lynne Gewant', 'Delray Beach, FL')
('Brian Morillo', 'Coral Springs, FL')
('Amanda Barcenas', 'Naples, FL')
('Jay Keller', 'Port St Lucie, FL')
('Darren Moreno', 'Lakeland, FL')
('344. Bascom Grooms ', '')
('Todd Richards', 'Boca Raton, FL')
('Dawn Giachetti - Realtor', 'Clermont, FL')
('Rochelle LeCavalier', 'Boca Raton, FL')
('Rhonda Keane Milligan', 'Cape Coral, FL')
('Roger Fruits', 'Tarpon Springs, FL')
('Jake Bestic', 'Ponte Vedra Beach, FL')
('351. Jeff Burns ', '')
('352. Claudia Rubio ', '')
('353. RADINKA ILSINK ', '')
('354. Jamie Seneca ', '')
('Ryan Kirby', 'Seminole, FL')
('The Get Smart Team', 'Jacksonville, FL')
('Pamela Vanderveer', 'Indian Harbour Beach, FL')
('358. Gwen Martin ', '')
('Andrew Butler', 'St Augustine, FL')
('Randal Jenkins', 'New Port Richey, FL')
('Carolyn Christian', 'Lakeland, FL')
('362. Mari Parks ', '')
('363. Carlos Rojas ', '')
('Jo-Ann Forster', 'Miami, FL')
('Gillian Redman', 'Davenport, FL')
('Shahram Sondi', 'Lake Mary, FL')
('367. Nancy Leslie ', '')
('368. Steve Rennick ', '')
('Krystal Arnold', 'Saint Petersburg, FL')
('Tammy Cook', 'Naples, FL')
('371. David Saka ', '')
('Lisset Franco', 'Naples, FL')
('Marc Diaz', 'Hollywood, FL')
('Patricia De Graaff', 'Winter Haven, FL')
('375. Gloria Frazier ', '')
('376. Gloria Frazier ', '')
('377. Allison Chance ', '')
('378. Kathleen Provancher ', '')
('Gail Bass', 'Boca Raton, FL')
('Alan Ivory', 'Crystal River, FL')
('Bryan Coward', 'Palm Harbor, FL')
('382. Gate Arty ', '')
('383. Chris Dowda ', '')
('Pablo Ramirez', 'Hialeah, FL')
('Jeffrey Petch', 'Winter Garden, FL')
('Meike MacGregor', 'Palm Beach Gardens, FL')
('Suzanne trammell', 'Ponte Vedra Beach, FL')
('388. Lee Brewer ', '')
('389. Gibbs Baum ', '')
('Matthew Jones', 'Panama City Beach, FL')
('Jayna Silverman', 'Atlantic Beach, FL')
('Elizabeth Schweitzer', 'Port Saint Lucie, FL')
('Terry Bailey', 'Deland, FL')
('Tasha Osbourne', 'Ocala, FL')
('Amy Ivey', 'Fort Myers, FL')
('Steve Shane', 'St Augustine, FL')
('Melva Garcia', 'Coconut Grove, FL')
('Brittany Zapitz', 'Winter Springs, FL')
('399. Ashleigh Quina ', '')
('Victoria Huscher', 'Spring Hill, FL')
('Brandi Furlan', 'Sarasota, FL')
('Kent Rodahaver', 'St Petersburg, FL')
('Deidre Vlassis', 'Palm Coast, FL')
('Renee Normandy-Shane', 'Port St. Lucie, FL')
('Caroleanne Vorac', 'Seminole, FL')
('406. Sonia Gaby Martinez ', '')
('407. Cindy Kauffman ', '')
('408. Judy Horvath ', '')
('409. Valerie Jarnberg ', '')
('Jason Jakus', 'Fort Myers, FL')
('411. Ryan Jennings ', '')
('412. Amy Greenfield ', '')
('413. Fanny Santos ', '')
('414. Mark Simoff ', '')
('Shane Clark', 'Tampa, FL')
('CURTIS GRIMES', 'Orlando, FL')
('Magda Paszkowski', 'Tarpon Springs, FL')
('Nicholas Rose', 'Jupiter, FL')
('Bobbie Jean DeMunck', 'Jacksonville, FL')
('420. Nick Polyushkin ', '')
('Mary Michael Martin', 'Sarasota, FL')
('Christina Diaz', 'Fort Myers, FL')
('Mary Johnson', 'St. George Island, FL')
('424. Erica Wolfe ', '')
('425. Nathanael Edwards ', '')
('426. Corey Edwards ', '')
('Kimberley Beaudry', 'Orlando, FL')
('Yasmin Saad PA', 'Naples, FL')
('Jason Ester', 'North Port, FL')
('Tracy Ward', 'Jupiter, FL')
('431. Kristen Rabell ', '')
('432. Elizabeth Hobart ', '')
('James Haviland', 'Ocala, FL')
('Beth Mulvey', 'Panama City Beach, FL')
('Justin Petrucci', 'St Augustine, FL')
('Kathy Aparo-Griffin', 'Deland, FL')
('Kim Tillett', 'Cocoa, FL')
('Daniel Larson', 'North Port, FL')
('Stacy Plean', 'Boynton Beach, FL')
('Kristina Fricke', 'Orlando, FL')
('Jeremy Reidenberg', 'Daytona Beach, FL')
('Lucas Gomez', 'Doral, FL')
('443. Kevin Kendrick ', '')
('444. Lisa Barton ', '')
('Chris Toomey', 'Ft Lauderdale, FL')
('Amy Mitchell', 'Homestead, FL')
('447. Michelle Daignault-Ives ', '')
('Marty Kaiser', 'Orlando, FL')
('Sharon Brandt', 'Kissimmee, FL')
('Ella Sari', 'Boca Raton, FL')
('451. Luke Andreae ', '')
('Steve Levin PA', 'Coral Springs, FL')
('453. Kym Coyle ', '')
('454. Alexandra Grossholz ', '')
('455. Jose Alonzo ', '')
('Ted Trawick', 'Fruitland Park, FL')
('Michele Frasure', 'Brandon, FL')
('458. Scott Needles ', '')
('459. Josh Dotoli ', '')
('460. Judi Taulbee ', '')
('461. Denise Chambre ', '')
('462. Tamara Celeste ', '')
('463. Alina Zimbran ', '')
('464. Lilli Schipper ', '')
('465. Carley Lane ', '')
('Nikki Musgrave', 'Tampa, FL')
('Alex Norkus', 'Jacksonville, FL')
('Gina Francis', 'Longwood, FL')
('Julie Hummel', 'Ft Myers, FL')
('Mary Zuver', 'Port St. Lucie, FL')
('471. Luis Padilla ', '')
('472. Michael Perrault ', '')
('473. Leslie Bennett ', '')
('474. Wesley Ulloa ', '')
('475. Michelle McKinney ', '')
('476. Scott Brucker ', '')
('Elizabeth Anthony', 'Ocala, FL')
('Jennifer Richards', 'Dunedin, FL')
('479. Renata Murphree ', '')
('480. Terry Holloway ', '')
('481. Mary Ann Miller ', '')
('482. Alex perez ', '')
('Hector Valdes', 'Fort Lauderdale, FL')
('Kyle Lambert Team', 'Ocala, FL')
('Abraham Mendez', 'Kissimmee, FL')
('Christine Pope,', 'Sarasota, FL')
('Nicky Nicole Reese', 'Jacksonville, FL')
('Casey Czapla', 'Jacksonville, FL')
('Todd Doss', 'Jensen Beach, FL')
('490. Kerryn Ellson ', '')
('491. Justin Watson ', '')
('492. SHERRY FELL ', '')
('493. Christian Panin ', '')
('Jennah LeBruno-Pust', 'Oviedo, FL')
('Alex Ellis', 'Saint Petersburg, FL')
('Tamara Aristy', 'Pompano Beach, FL')
('Daniel Kalina', 'Port Saint Lucie, FL')
('Tracie Trotter', 'Spring Hill, FL')
('499. Eric Levy ', '')
('500. David Padot ', '')
```